# DropDownListFor not preselecting value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm building an MVC web application and am about to run my head through the wall, there's a dozen topics on this already and all have accepted solutions that do not work for me. There's probably something really stupid and simple I'm forgetting/not seeing, but can't seem to work it out.
Please don't hate me for naming; I'm continuing a project started by someone else.

I have the following line in my ManageDetail.cshtml:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.ChecklistWaarde.SoortID, Model.ChecklistOptionsOptions, "Choose a value", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

This builds a selectbox based on property Model.ChecklistWaarde.SoortID, which is an integer. The next parameter passed is a SelectList from the model that is generated by the following very simple helper function that does a DB lookup in a 2ndary database (unfortunately), it receives the parameter SoortID as well to set a preselect value:

```
public SelectList GetChecklistOptions(int selectedId = -1)
    {
        var soorten = new List<SelectListItem>();
        try
        {
            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(mssqlConnectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();
                SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand();
                command.CommandText = "Select Naam, ID From ChecklistSoorten";
                SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    var id = reader["ID"] as int?;
                    if (id.HasValue)
                    {
                        soorten.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = reader["Naam"] as string, Value = id.Value.ToString(), Selected = id.Value.Equals(selectedId) });
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Globals.Log.Error(ex);
        }

        return new SelectList(soorten, "Value", "Text");            
    }
```

It gets called in the controller like this:

```
public ActionResult ManageDetail(int? id) {
    var model = new MachineDetailsModel(id);
    model.ChecklistOptionsOptions = sqlDal.GetChecklistOptions(model.ChecklistWaarde.SoortID);
    return View("ManageDetail", model); 
}
```

When I try to debug my code, I can see that the model values are populated correctly:

- `SoortID` has a value of 2 (`int`)
- `Model.ChecklistOptionsOptions` has a populated`SelectLis`t
- Upon inspecting the `SelectList` I find that only item with value "2" has property `Selected = true`, this is `false` for all others.
- When the form gets rendered, it will not select the item with value 2, rather it will have the first item selected, "Choose a value"
- Inspecting the HTML, I see that the item with value 2 is indeed not selected, contrary to what I was expecting (see HTML below; shorted the list in count and text for readability). I expected to see "selected" on the line for item 2, as it was selected in the `SelectList`.

```html
  <select class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field SoortID must be a number." data-val-required="The SoortID field is required." id="ChecklistWaarde_SoortID" name="ChecklistWaarde.SoortID" style="min-width:100%;">
            <option value="">Choose a value</option>
      <option value="1">Item A</option>
      <option value="2">Item B</option>
      <option value="3">Item C</option>
      <option value="4">Item D</option>
     </select>
```

What am I missing? How can I make item with value "2" select, as it is in the `SelectList` that I pass to the `DropDownListFor()` function?

Comment: You need to set the value of property `SoortID` in the GET method before you pass the model to the view. And setting the `Selected` property of `SelectListItem` is pointless (its ignored when binding to a model property). And even more pointless is creating another `SelectList` from the first one using `new SelectList(...)` - just use `return soorten;`

Comment: @StephenMuecke SoortID gets set in the constructor of the model so it is already set in the view.
Good suggestion on just passing the list soorten instead of a new SelectList  will change that.

Comment: If the value of `SoortID` matches one of you options then it WILL be selected in the view. And if its not, then there is something else you are not telling us.

Comment: Try rendering the id next to the dropdown list for eg `@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.ChecklistWaarde.SoortID). If this is blank then you know the data nevwer makes it into the view.

Comment: @StephenMuecke it now selects the item correctly (if the value is passed to the SelectList constructor which I did not do before), thanks for pointing out that the Selected property gets lost when the model is bound, I did not realize that.

Comment: @ste-fu Tried that after posting here indeed, just to be sure, but the model was populated correctly, as debugging already indicated. Problem solved though, thanks for chipping in!

Comment: @DJDev, Then then you are doing something else wrong or have not told us the real story. As I noted previously, its the value of the property hat determines what is selected and the `DropDownListFor()` method builds its own `SelectList` and ignores the `Selected` property (the 4th parameter of the `SelectList` constructor sets the `Selected` property!!)

Comment: My best guess is that you have some kind of loop in the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the controller where you are populating `SelectList`, set selected value there, your code would look like:

```
if (id.HasValue)
{
     soorten.Add(new SelectListItem 
                    { 
                      Text = reader["Naam"] as string, 
                      Value = id.Value.ToString() 
                    });
}
```

and then down at the line of instantiating `SelectList`:

```
return new SelectList(soorten, "Value", "Text",selectedId);
```

or you could elminate `SelectList` and instead in your model change the property `ChecklistOptionsOptions` type to `List<SelectListItem>`, in that case the last line of creating `SelectList` will not be required further, right now you are creating it multiple times.

Comment: Indeed, instead of passing the selectedId as 4th parameter to the SelectList constructor, I set Selected for the SelectListItem itself, and as mentioned by Stephen Muecke. Changing my code to pass it to the constructor of SelectList does work - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately everything in the view that gets rendered comes from `ViewData`. This takes the model, but also request data and 'ModelState`.

I have had this sort of problem when some of the request parameters have a name conflict with some of the model parameters. This overrides the value in the model and causes the issue.

It is very difficult to debug, as it normally appears that all the correct values have been set. Check all your parameter names if in doubt.